# Can't output values from Rails ActionText

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, actiontext

UPDATE: This seems to be happening on an `--api` only build, which is what I use. It can be reproduced by creating a new rails project with the `--api` flag.

`@model.content.body.to_html` seems to return the proper content.

---

I am having a problem using ActionText. I've had this problem for a while, and I can't find any answers online, so I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot.

Sometimes, I can't get access to the ActionText values.

I included this in my `Section` model:

`has_rich_text :content`

I can set the data by doing:

```
@section.content = "<p>Hello world</p>"
```

However, I cannot see the text in my console, nor erb templates. I see it just as an empty string, or in the mailer template, it doesn't show up at all.

```
section.content
=> #<ActionText::RichText id: 1, name: "content", body: #<ActionText::Content " ">, record_type: "Section", record_id: "f9c5743c-fb16-411e-82ad-325817849a40", created_at: "2020-05-09 14:54:48", updated_at: "2020-05-13 01:35:34">

section.content.body
=> #<ActionText::Content " ">

section.content.body.to_s
=> " "

section.content.to_json
=> "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"content\",\"body\":\"\\u003cdiv\\u003e\\u003c!--block--\\u003eThis is an overview for Chapter 1.\\u003c/div\\u003e\",\"record_type\":\"Section\",\"record_id\":\"f9c5743c-fb16-411e-82ad-325817849a40\",\"created_at\":\"2020-05-09T10:54:48.633-04:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-05-12T21:35:34.546-04:00\"}"

section.content.body.to_json
=> "\"\\u003cdiv\\u003e\\u003c!--block--\\u003eThis is an overview for Chapter 1.\\u003c/div\\u003e\""
```

I can't seem to access the value, unless I convert it to JSON. The value gets pulled fine in my API Serializer as well, but that is also JSON. I can't access it from the rails console, nor in my mailer templates, and I'm currrently outputting it in my template like this:

```
<%= JSON.parse(@chapter.sections.first.content.body.to_json).html_safe %>
```

How do I get access to the value, or any thoughts on how to troubleshoot?

Thank you.

```
Rails 6.0.3
ruby 2.7.1p83
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, works fine for me. There must be something else going on with your setup, models etc....

Comment: I created a brand new project and it's the same issue. ActionText seems to work in a regular Rails app, but is not working with the `--api` flag, and my app is an api only app.